# Using $location.protocol() and $location.host() in Vuejs application

Tags: rest, vue.js, vuejs2

I have one application in angularJs where I use `$location.protocol() + '://' + $location.host()` when I'm dealing with API calls.

Example:

```
return $http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: $location.protocol() + '://' + $location.host() + '/rest/api/category/category',
    headers: {
        'Jwt-token': store.get('jwt')
    }
})
```

Now I'm building another application in VUEjs and i also wan't to use same "$location" logic to call API, but I don't know how.

My current implementation is hardcoding url

Example:

```
getCategories() {
    fetch(`http://myapp.test/rest/api/category/category`, {
        method: 'GET'
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => this.categories = json)
}
```

How to properly "translate/convert" the code (`$location.protocol() + '://' + $location.host()`) from my Angular app to VueJs? If you need any additional information's please let me know and I will provide! Thank you!

Comment: Why don't you just use relative urls `fetch('/rest/api/category/category')`?

Comment: Use any of these: (1) relative URLs, (2) Protocol relative URLs (ex: //myapp.test/rest/api/category/category) or (3) window.location.protocol + "://" + window.location.host

Comment: Because this VUE app is running via npm run dev (so http://localhost:8080), other REST api application is currently runed via MAMP (so via virtualhost myapp.test)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use can use the DOM api inside Vue applications:

- `document.location.protocol` for protocol
- `document.location.host` for the current host
- or just `document.location.origin` for `protocol+'://'+host`